Dual of the sum of dual metrics
Suppose I have a (smooth, connected, compact) Riemannian manifold $M$ and two smooth metric tensors $g_1$ and $g_2$. I can define the metric tensor $g:= (g_1^\star+g_2^\star)^\star$ where for a tensor $T$, $T^\star$ denotes the inverse tensor. Is there any paper/textbook where this construction is treated? I am interested in particular in the relation between the exponential map of $g$ and the ones of $g_1$ and $g_2$.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Any chance you'd be willing to say a little about why you're interested in this? You should probably start by studying the inner product $$v\cdot(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}w,$$ where $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices.

This is connected to this other question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872193/mixing-metric-tensors-on-riemannian-manifold
The idea is that the metric $d'$ there is precisely induced by the metric tensor $g$ as above. In order to compare it to the metric $d''$ there, I think that the study of the relation between the exponential maps could be relevant. In case of flat metrics I already proved the equivalence in my other post (still no study of the exponential maps was needed).
